# Best place for shut down hook

Tags: java

I have a main() method that calls a Thread class and starts a thread. This thread has a while(threadBool) loop, so I need to stop it when I exit the program ( by setting threadBool to false). Where is the best place to place addShutdownHook()? In the main() method

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                class.threadBool=false;
            }
        }));
```

or in the same class that started this thread

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                threadBool=false;
            }
        }));
```

Comment: When you System.exit it kills all the existing user threads. What are you trying to shutdown by setting this flag?

Comment: Why not make the thread pool daemon?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The best place is nowhere at all. Shutdown hooks are only a last-resort effort due to an unexpected interuption of the program to salvage what can be salvaged.

You should instead organize your code so that there is a cleanly defined entry point, main body, and exit point. You can then stop your thread at the exit point.